# seeking details on ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher class

Tags: ros

I recently came across 'ros::SingleSubscriberPubliser' class. The [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1SingleSubscriberPublisher.html#details) describes it as 'Allows publication of a message to a single subscriber. Only available inside subscriber connection callbacks'.

What does 'subscriber connection callbacks' mean?

Also, when does it make sense to use this class?

Answer (score 2):

The subscriber connection callback is triggered when there's a new subscriber connected to a publisher.

There's documentation of how you can use that function in the [Node Handle Documentation](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/b9bd85debbfebeb8301cf40b24415546b22e5632/clients/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h#L257-L314)

It's not a commonly used feature. I don't know what your use case is but would gess that it is not something that you want to try to leverage.